# How to get matrix of mySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, optimization, pivot

I have a simple table describing cells like this. This table `cells` contains 3 fields: `column_id`, `row_id`, `value`. This table can NOT have a value for same couple `(column_id, row_id)`.

For example, this contains theses values :

```
id  column_id   row_id   value
1   0           0        'a'
2   0           1        'b'
3   1           0        'c'
```

This is very "simple" here for the example, but there is more than 20.000 rows and 50 columns.

I'm searching a rapid method to get the result as a matrix, like Excel does:

```
row_id   column_0   column_1
0        'a'        'c'
1        'b'         NULL
```

For now, I success with a set of SELECT, like this

```
SELECT row_id,
  SELECT (value FROM cells AS cells_row_1 WHERE cells.row_id=cells_row_1.row_id AND column_id=1) AS column_1,
  SELECT (value FROM cells AS cells_row_2 WHERE cells.row_id=cells_row_2.row_id AND column_id=2) AS column_2
FROM cells
```

This query is not readable and not optimized.
Do you have a better idea to do this ?

Regards

Comment: I don't think there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT row_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.column_id = 1 THEN c.value ELSE '' END) AS column_1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.column_id = 2 THEN c.value ELSE '' END) AS column_2
FROM cells c
GROUP BY c.row_id;
```

If you want to fetch columns dynamically then use below code:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN c.column_id = ', c.column_id, ' THEN c.value ELSE '''' END) AS column_', c.column_id) INTO @query 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column_id FROM cells c) AS c;

SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT row_id, ", @query,  "FROM cells c GROUP BY c.row_id;");

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```